# @if (!empty(...)) is ignored although no data returning in an object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to show the comments if the incoming object is `!empty` as follows.

```
@if(!empty($comments))

            <h3>Other people comments</h3>

          @foreach ($comments as $comment)
             <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
          @endforeach
@endif
```

But the problem is, `!empty` is always ignored, and the `<h3>Other people comments</h3>` is always showing although no comments are there.

The following is var_dump for $comments

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#354 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$comments` is not empty, it contains an object. There is a [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-count) method you can use to determine if the collection has any items in it.

```
@if($comments->count())
```

Answer (score 0):

**$comments** is actually a collection with 0 element, so empty() will return false.
Try:

```
@if(count($comments))
   ...
@endif
```